# Getting Facebook video ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, youtube

I've made a script that gets the ID for YouTube and Vimeo, but I am not sure how to get the ID from the Facebook embed URL.

Example embed:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHammers.Serbia.Official%2Fvideos%2F1261009690594307%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

I need to get the ID which in this case is: 1261009690594307

How can I it with YouTube? I am new to JS so not sure how to replicate but getting the ID for this one.

```
$.each($('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]'), function() {
    var player = $('<div class="video-player">');
    var id = $(this).attr('src');
    id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    player.attr('data-id', id);
    player.html(videoThumbYT(id));
    player.on('click', videoIframeYT);
    
    var videoContainer = $('<div class="video-container">');
    videoContainer.append(player);
    $(this).replaceWith(videoContainer);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest using the **[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)**.

```
function fbvideoID(frame) {
  var myRegexp = /2F(\d+)%/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(frame);
  return match[1];
}

var facebookVideo = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHammers.Serbia.Official%2Fvideos%2F1261009690594307%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>';

document.write(fbvideoID(myString)); //returns ID 1261009690594307
```

### Explanation

Regular Expression

```
/2F(\d+)%/g
```

Selects the ID. Test it **[here](http://www.regexpal.com/)!**

```
var match = myRegexp.exec(frame);
```

Returns array of two elements. Documentation **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).**

```
0: "2F1261009690594307%"
1: "1261009690594307"
```

The 0 index is **always** the whole expression. The 1 is only the `(\d+)` - **braces.** Which contains our ID.

**Hope I helped you!**

Comment: Thanks mate, got it working based on your solution :)

Comment: Just trying to get it to add the SDK so i can reload the video with better markup and auto play but not cracked it yet lol

Comment: @James What's wrong? Eventually make a new question with code and send me the link. I'll try to help you

Comment: Thanks mate, it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189246/jquery-forcing-click-action-on-generated-iframe-so-it-autoplays?noredirect=1#comment61920522_37189246 - the youtube and vimeo i done when you click plays video but can set autoplay but facebook i dont think can on iframe so need to force the click once its loaded i guess.... thanks for the help mate. Hope your around tonight as need to do a release this evening haha thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, could be refined a bit.

```
$.each($('iframe[src*="facebook.com/plugins/video"]'), function() {

    var url = decodeURIComponent($(this).attr('src'));
    var id = url.match(/\/\d+\//);
    if (id) {
        id = id.slice(1,-1);
        console.log(id);
        //do your player stuff here.
    }
});
```