# jQuery - Forcing click action on generated iframe so it autoplays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

Im rather new to jQuery / JS and trying to auto click a generated iframe so that is plays the video as dont think autoplay works when setting in the iframes url, is it possible and maybe im going about it wrong?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p7v34x57/1/

JS:

```
$.each($('iframe[src*="facebook.com/plugins/video"]'), function() {
  var getId = $(this).attr('src');
  var player = $('<div class="video-player">');
  var id = fbvideoID(getId);
  player.attr('data-id', id);
  player.html(videoThumbFB(id));
  player.on('click', videoIframeFB);

  var videoContainer = $('<div class="video-container">');
  videoContainer.append(player);
  $(this).replaceWith(videoContainer);
});

function fbvideoID(frame) {
  var myRegexp = /2F(\d+)%/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(frame);
  return match[1];
}

function videoThumbFB(id) {
  return '<img class="facebook-thumb" src="//graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function videoIframeFB() {
  var wrap = $('<iframe>');
  wrap.attr("src", "//www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=" +          $(this).attr('data-id') + "&amp;autoplay=1");
  wrap.attr("frameborder", "0");
  wrap.addClass("facebook-iframe");
  $(this).empty();
  $(this).append(wrap);

  videoClickFB();
}

function videoClickFB(){
    $('.facebook-iframe').click();
}
```

Comment: "i don't think it works" - did you actually try or do you KNOW it does not work? either way, trying to auto-click it would definitely be a very bad way. you should never do stuff like that.

Comment: If you check out the fiddle, it shows black background image which is the thumbnail pulled from facebook that they have for the video and overlays with my play icon - when you click it, it removes and loads the facebook video in place which is fine but i want it to then start playing... if you click it again it plays but makes no sense having to click it twice :)

Comment: If you look here with what i done with youtube and vimeo you will see what i mean.... https://jsfiddle.net/yurt5bb6/5/ - those auto play as can set in the iframe url but facebook cant with iframe embed.